# Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

added in layout

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") why script render is address inside render a bundle?\